# Default selected option doesn't work in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a view

```
<select ng-model="selected_student" class="form-control">
    <option ng-repeat="obj in students" value="{{obj.id}}">{{obj.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I am doing this in `controller`:

`$scope.selected_student = $scope.students[0];`

why it doesn't work?

Here's my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qeszsLLy/)

Comment: "$scope.selected_student = $scope.students[0];" writing this in your controller what is your goal? i mean that do you want to get student id as selected_student ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ng-options`:

```
 <select ng-model="selected_student" class="form-control" ng-options="student.id as student.name for student in students">
```

And in `controller`:

```
$scope.selected_student = $scope.students[0].id;
```

Working jsfiddle link:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/avnesh2/boye4ezk/
```

Will work for you.

Comment: `ng-option` looks better for your requirement and it's binding `student.name` based on `student.id`. See for [detail](https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/08/11/a-brief-walk-through-of-the-ng-options-in-angularjs/)